# Can I have optimization on, but not suffer from reordered statements?

Tags: c, gcc

My debug CFLAGS were always `-g -O0`. The latter mainly to disable jumps to unexpected line while debugging. Nowadays more and more programs refuse to compile with -O0, besides, `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` require optimizer.

is it possible to compile with `-O`, but have predictable behavior in debugger?

Comment: How do programs refuse to compile with -O0?

Comment: @minitech https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49653

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/201207/msg00189.html

Comment: With Wireshark and similar cases, just remove `-Werror`.

Comment: If the code doesn't compile with -O0, that's a clear sign that the code is broken, and you should fix it before trying further debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GCC 4.8 or above, try using `-g -Og`. As explained in [the release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html):

> A new general optimization level, -Og, has been introduced. It addresses the need for fast compilation and a superior debugging experience while providing a reasonable level of run-time performance. Overall experience for development should be better than the default optimization level -O0.

Comment: `(gdb) print buff 
$3 = <optimized out>` dang!

Comment: I will compile most of the sources with `-O0`. Those, which can't - with `-Og`